# Filter a dataframe with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hey I want to make this code work:

```
data = data %>% filter(value1=="city" & !is.na(value2)) %>% group_by(A_id, B_id)  %>%
    filter(date==min(as.Date(date,"%d.%m.%Y"))) %>% select(A_id, B_id, date)
```

I get the following error: Caused by error in `charToDate()`, character string is not in a standard unambiguous format. But if I work with the date column in other lines of code it works fine... Doesnt help to change it to date format before the filtering, same error..

This is my existing dataframe for the example A_id and B_id:

| A_id | B_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2020 |
| 1 | 1 | 01.11.2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 05.12.2019 |
| 1 | 2 | 31.01.2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 05.12.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 01.11.2021 |
| 2 | 3 | 01.11.2021 |
| 2 | 3 | 31.01.2020 |

I would like to receive the following table: (which date format exactly doesnt matter)

| A_id | B_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.01.2020 |
| 1 | 2 | 05.12.2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 05.12.2019 |
| 2 | 3 | 31.01.2020 |

Anybody who could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice_min` which takes the minimum value in each group:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(A_id, B_id) %>%
  slice_min(as.Date(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))
```

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   A_id, B_id [4]
   A_id  B_id date      
  <int> <int> <chr>     
1     1     1 01.01.2020
2     1     2 05.12.2019
3     2     1 05.12.2019
4     2     3 31.01.2020
```

---

If you wanna keep `filter`, you should format your string on both sides:

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(A_id, B_id) %>%
  filter(as.Date(date,"%d.%m.%Y") == min(as.Date(date,"%d.%m.%Y")))
```

Comment: thanks,  both worked! if I only want to keep the min date row (in this example row 2 for A_id =1 and row 3 for A_id=2) what would I have to add to this?

Comment: You can do: `data %>% 
  group_by(A_id) %>%
  slice_min(as.Date(date, "%d.%m.%Y"))`, i.e. only grouping by A_id